# How long should I wait before using my electric oven after using WD-40 on the element mounting screws?

Tags: cleaning, oven

I had some rusted mounting screws that were holding the heating element in my electric oven. I sprayed them with WD-40 and got the element replacement put in. I have wiped the area down.

How long before I can use my oven would you suggest?

Answer (score 4):

I did the same thing but with PB Blaster (it smells even worse than WD-40) for an outdoor kitchen. I just wiped it down with soapy water and ran the oven at 425 with the door open for about 10 minutes before putting any food in it. There really wasn't any smell or smoke because the petroleum distillates burn off very fast.